# How to make a panel appear when the mouse moves over it? delphi

Tags: delphi, mouse, visible

How can I make a panel appear with everything that is in it when I move my mouse over its location?

When I move it off again, it fades back out?

Doing it when it is visible is not a problem (except the fading out), I can do this with onmouseleaves.

But when it is invisible how do you make it visible?

thankssss

Comment: Have you looked into using a proper docking library for Delphi instead of making a kludge  (partially working solution)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the panel on another (blank) panel. Make the "magic" panel show up when you get mouse movement over the blank panel.

---

Edited, because I now learned the OP has the Panel over a WebBrowser. My solution of placing an dummy / blank panel no longer works; Interfering with mouse messages going to the WebBrowser is also not a good idea, so here's a simple way to fix this. I'm using an TTimer with it's interval set to "100" and I'm pooling the mouse coordinates.

```
procedure TForm25.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var PR: TRect; // Panel Rect (in screen coordinates)
    CP: TPoint; // Cursor Position (always in screen coordinates)
begin
  // Get the panel's coordinates and convert them to Screen coordinates.
  PR.TopLeft := Panel1.ClientToScreen(Panel1.ClientRect.TopLeft);
  PR.BottomRight := Panel1.ClientToScreen(Panel1.ClientRect.BottomRight);
  // Get the mouse cursor position
  CP := Mouse.CursorPos;
  // Is the cursor over the panel?
  if (CP.X >= PR.Left) and (CP.X <= PR.Right) and (CP.Y >= PR.Top) and (CP.Y <= PR.Bottom) then
    begin
      // Panel should be made visible
      Panel1.Visible := True;
    end
  else
    begin
      // Panel should be hidden
      Panel1.Visible := False;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Wait. This guy wants mouse over the entire region to cause the panel to come back up again? That's kind of against docking "conventions" that enforce usability.

Comment: I think he wants some kind of info panel that only shows up when you move your mouse into the area and fades away when you move out. It's not that unconventional, and it's not about docking. Well, at least that's how I understood the question!

Comment: Is the fading out difficult? panels don't seemt to have alphablend

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: Surely you know that lines 11-20 can be written *as a single line*, all ten of them? I guess you are just being extra clear to the OP, but it still hurts my eyes!

Comment: @Andreas, I guess `Panel1.Visible := PtInRect(PR, CP)` does look slightly better. The omission was the `PtInRect` routine, I knew it must exist, but didn't feel like googling it. The explicit if is intentional.

Comment: @frum, I can think of a solution or two, but I'm not an expert on GDI: For best results ask an other question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an area that your panel will appear in, you can capture the mouse move event for the underlying form or parent panel and check it is within the bounds that your invisible panel will appear in.

eg. (pseudocode)

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if ((X > MyPanel.Left) and (Y > MyPanel.Top) and (X < mypanel.right) and 
  (Y < mypanel.bottom)) then
  begin
      mypanel.visible := true;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: that would make sense thank you, but what if my delphi doesn't recognize right and bottom?

Comment: You replace `mypanel.right` with `(mypanel.Left + mypanel.Width)`

Comment: Thx, Although it doesn't seem to work when there is something behind it.

Comment: I have a webbrowser behind it

Comment: It doesn't work because mouse messages go to the top-most window that's visible and it's under the cursor (unless the mouse cursor is "captured"). If there's something behind the panel, that thing's receiving the mouse messages, not the Form.